# unsupported video format handling

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using **MPMoviePlayerController** to play videos. I want to show an alert to user when the given video does not have a supported format. But I am not getting any error from SDK about it.

When I try to run any unsupported video , it leaves me with **MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded** and the following error in the console.

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

Does anyone know about how to handle it?

Comment: Which notification are you receiving?

Comment: @GuyKogus I receive MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried examining the `errorLog` property of [MPMoviePlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/errorLog)?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this.

> [[[notification userInfo]valueForKey:@"error"] localizedDescription];

This works for me and gives "can not open" for the unsupported formats. Hope it helps others looking for similar problems.